# Fix XML that has unescaped characters in R

Tags: r, regex, xml, stringr

From a software, I get an output similar to `test_text` where there are two unescaped inequality operators (<, >).

```
test_text <- '
  <variables>
    <aux name = "var1">
      IF_THEN_ELSE(a > b :AND: a <= c , a, 0)
    </aux>
  </variables>'
```

How could I replace such operators for their respective escaped versions ("&lt" and "&gt") using regex to obtain the following:

```
expected_output <- '
  <variables>
    <aux name = "var1">
      IF_THEN_ELSE(a &gt; b :AND: a &lt;= c , a, 0)
    </aux>
  </variables>'
```

Comment: Could you please provide your current code so that we could understand the problem better?